# Chaining commands in linux

Tags: php, shell, pid

I am trying to chain a series of commands, have them run as background processes in linux and get the process id of at least the second of those commands. The idea is to have a delay as the first function, do some work on the second function and the third would notify of the second functions completion.

Is this possible and if so how would you write the command?

```
$pid = `(sleep 3s ; php -F something.php ; php -F something_is_finished.php) & echo #!`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php%20%27%27proc_open%27%27) and [`proc_get_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php%20%27%27proc_get_status%27%27) functions for this. The latter will allow you to get your PID.